# Displaying a Box on an HTML page using external Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

When a submit button is clicked on an HTML page a box should display anywhere on the page of any color also. I am using an external JavaScript page to accomplish this. However, it isn't working... I tried to debug it and it wont get past the point of `var body = document.getElementsById("body")[0];`

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Exercise 2 - Question 2</title>
        <script src="E02_Q2.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form> 
            <input type="submit" value="Add Box" onclick="ShowBox()"/>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here is the External Javascript to accompany it:

```
function ShowBox(){
    //get the body element of the document
    var body = document.getElementsById("body")[0];

    //create the canvas tag
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.height = 200;
    canvas.width = 200;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //create the box and append onto the canvas 
    canvas.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    canvas.fillRect(50,50,100,100); 

    //append the canvas onto the body 
    body.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

Not quite sure where i'm going wrong here...

Comment: You have 2 errors in your first js line `var body = document.getElementsById("body")[0]` - `getElementsById` meghod does not exist, there is `getElementById` and second, that method would return a single element, not an array that you're referencing. I am guessing you meant `document.getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Haha, yeah, I was not sure there were no more errors, so did not attempt to answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

**First**, There is a mistake in the below line. (You don't have any element with `id` as `body` and even if there had been an element with `id='body'` the method is not `getElementsById`, it should be `getElementById`.)

```
var body = document.getElementsById("body")[0];
```

Instead it should be like below using `getElementsByTagName`

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

**Second**, `fillStyle` and `fillRect` should be on `context` and not `canvas`.

```
context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
context.fillRect(50,50,100,100);
```

**Third**, you have to `return false;` to prevent the default action of the `submit` button like below:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Box" onclick="ShowBox();return false;"/>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/8hRY3/)

Answer (score 1):

Change form button to normal button. Otherwise add return false in the function.

```
<form> 
        <input type="button" value="Add Box" onclick="ShowBox()"/>
</form>
```

There are more errors in the function., please check the script below.

Eg : http://jsfiddle.net/3EwxB/

```
function ShowBox(){

     var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    //create the canvas tag
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.height = 200;
    canvas.width = 200;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //create the box and append onto the canvas 
    context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    context.fillRect(50,50,100,100); 

    //append the canvas onto the body 
    body.appendChild(canvas);

}
```

Comment: did you checked my jsfiddle link. which browser you are testing. I've tested in chrome.

Comment: @user2619395: Did you `return false;` from the submit button action? Else, the submit button will redirect it by default. I have not seen Mansoorkhan Cherupuzha's fiddle, but if you want you can have a look at the one I posted.

Comment: yes it need return false other wise it will redirect to action page. but we can't add return false, because, we need to post the from. otherwise change submit button to normal button.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha: OP says that only a box should be displayed on submit, so perhaps there is no need to post the form. But only OP can clarify.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha: If you need to post the form, changing the button to `button` is also not much help isn't it? Then we might have to submit it artificially through JS code.

Comment: @Harry, If the user need only to show the box, it is better to use type button.because, in that form only a button is there.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha: All that only OP can clarify because we only see this part of the code. What is there in the rest we don't know :) Should I move this discussion to a chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37763/discussion-between-mansoorkhan-cherupuzha-and-harry)